# Facebook page plugin doesn't respond to width

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe

OK so I am trying to embed a Facebook page on a website and am having issues with responding to device width. I have read on this site that the Facebook page plugin has a max-width of 500px and that if `adapt_container_width` is set to true, the content of the iframe should scale down to fill the container width. I have set the `iframe` width to be `100%` but when I view on a device with a small screen i.e. iPhone, the content of the iframe is not resizing and is instead being clipped.

This is the iframe code I am using:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebook%2F%3Fref&amp;tabs=timeline&amp;width=500&amp;height=500&amp;small_header=true&amp;adapt_container_width=true&amp;hide_cover=true&amp;show_facepile=false&amp;appId=526762070849187" width="100%" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `adapt_container_width` does not mean it will resize dynamically - it will only adapt to the screen once on initial load.

Comment: Ok but even on initial load, the content doesn't fit the width of the iframe when its below 500px and greater than 180px.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/#adaptive-width describes how it is supposed to work. If it doesn’t, you can file a bug report with Facebook if you think it is their fault.

Comment: Ok will re-read it all and may have to do that :P